# Calendar will not minimize

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Does anyone know why a Calendar webpart will not minimize?  If I have it viewed as a list, All Events, for example, it will minimize.  If it's viewed as a calendar, it will not.  All other webparts of other types on the page will minimize.  I'm using SharePoint 2013, and IE11.

Comment: Are you using a custom master page when you have this issue?

Comment: Nope, just on a regular wiki page.

Comment: Is this in edit mode? What does happen when you try to minimize it through the web part drop down?

Comment: I can minimize it in edit mode, but when I save, it still expands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full-size calendar can't be minimized and saved in that state on a wiki page. You have a couple of options:

1. Change the page over to a web part page (or even just a non-wiki page) and then change the part as minimized and save the page. It should save minimized there.
2. Change the view on the wiki page calendar web part to
   Summary View, apply the change to the page and then set the web part
   to minimized. yes, this removes the calendar part, but does show the
   calendar data.
3. Add a script web part w/ CSS to have the calendar web part marked
   not visibile and then reveal it when clicked through JavaScript.
4. Just have a Content web part and link to the full calendar view web page.

Blame Microsoft for the weirdness of this one.

Comment: 1) Doesn't work on a web part page, either. 2) My boss wants calendars, and won't be talked out of it!  3) This I think is my ultimate solution, unfortunately, I'm slowly trying to teach myself CSS, JavaScript, and HTML as I go along; leaving me with 4) This works for the time being! Definitely not as elegant of a solution, but until I can learn to program something better, thank you very much for the suggestion.